# Do I have to assign a function result to a variable before I return it?

Tags: javascript

I expected the following 2 code snippets to be equivalent:

```
function waitFirstLoadHTML(message) {
    var r = '<div class="form-blocker">' +
    '<span class="ui-corner-all">' + message + '</span>' +
    '</div>';
    return r;
}
```

and

```
function waitFirstLoadHTML(message) {
    return '<div class="form-blocker">' +
    '<span class="ui-corner-all">' + message + '</span>' +
    '</div>';
}
```

But somehow the first one returns the string value as expected, while the second one returns `undefined`. Any idea why?

Comment: It works just fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/JFPzV/

Comment: @smccone: yea as it should. But in my page it does not. I spent an hour and narrowed down my problem to this function. If I run the page with the latter - it fails, with the former - it works. And now I am lost - what I could've done to break the latter but not the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always had trouble putting strings over multiple lines in JavaScript - does it work if you do:

```
function waitFirstLoadHTML(message)
{
    return '<div class="form-blocker"><span class="ui-corner-all">'+message+'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: did not think of this one - split the lines for better readability. What kind of troubles did you have?

Comment: I've always had errors when trying to place a value over multiple lines in JS - not sure why.. At best for readability I'd do like.. var html = ''; html += '<div>'; html += 'content'; html += '</div>'; return html;

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine. If you are looking at the result in a browser by say:

```
document.write(waitFirstLoadHTML(undefined));
```

It's going to show as `undefined` but the actual string is:

```
<div class="form-blocker"><span class="ui-corner-all">undefined</span></div>
```

Are you sure you aren't missing something from your example?

Comment: Of course if the parameter is 'undefined' the resulting string will include the word "undefined", but the type of the result would still be a string. The problem I have is that the result returned is not a string, and the JQuery function I am trying to feed it to does not recognize it as such

Comment: @mfeingold - You need to supply a more complete example then, as what you've posted above works as expected, so your problem must be with something else.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, there is no need for you to split the return over two statements (unless you want to).  I think there might be something else going on missing from that example?